# How do I install LLVM/Clang 3.0?

Tags: software-installation

So LLVM 3.0 has been released, and I’d like to use it on my Ubuntu 11.10 system.  On the [LLVM Download Page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.0), there are tarballs for LLVM+Clang 3.0 built for Ubuntu 11.10 (and 11.04, and other systems) in x86 & x86_64 flavors.  I see that 12.04 will have LLMV 3.0 from the package manager, but there do not seem to be any PPAs with the new version for older Ubuntu releases, nor is 3.0 available in the back-ports.

I could, I suppose, unpack the tarballs into `/usr/local`, and then remove it if/when “offical” back-ports become available, but is that my best option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would unpack the ubuntu binary to `/usr/local` and install the .deb when it becomes available, either in a ppa or as a backports.

Comment: could you please explain installing procedure, I Download the llvm and I have 5 folders which names are `bin`,`include`,`lib`,`libexec` and `share` how I can install llvm with using this folders?

Comment: @saeedmasoomi you do realize this question / answer is from 2011 and is asking about a version of Ubuntu that is no longer supported ? I suggest you ask a new question about a supported release and be specific as to what you are trying to do.