# How to install clang 3.0

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install LLVM/Clang 3.0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89615/how-do-i-install-llvm-clang-3-0)

I'm around 3 days old in Ubuntu and not aware of it's basics. I am trying to install [clang 3.0](http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/clang+llvm-3.0-i386-linux-Ubuntu-11_10.tar.gz) on system. But I've no idea what to do after getting the package.

Can any please help me in steps how to install the binaries?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this specific version of Clang, the 3.0, take a look here:

http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

Otherwise, if installing a previous version of Clang is fine for you, then you can install it through the Ubuntu Software Centre:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/clang/

Comment: That guide from clang is really worst to be understood by beginner (atleast for me). That's why I requested for steps in this Q. If you know doing this, please help me with steps?